# Facebook Canvas iframe not loading the URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-canvas

I am developing a rummy game over the facebook. But after few days facebook canvas iframe is throwing an error which i have given below:

**Not Found**

The requested URL /stats.php was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
*Apache/1.3.41 Server at cabaniaseleden.com.ar Port 80*

And here is the link of the application: [rummy_game](http://apps.facebook.com/rummy_game)
So please help me out to remove this problem as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**File Not Found**,
check if you can direct [open](http://cabaniaseleden.com.ar/stats.php) the file, if it's ok then you will have the ability to get this inside Facebook. Now it's not possible.

**SSL Error** - (*SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length*),
maybe you are using a self signed ssl or missing Apache configuration.

[image]

Check your link's and have in mind that you will need a valid SSL.

Answer (score 0):

Canvas is loaded correctly but pointing to non existing URL (`http://cabaniaseleden.com.ar/stats.php`), which should be fixed on your end by editing application settings:

[image: Application settings]

Comment: I have added both the Canvas URL as well as Secure Canvas URL also but there is no solution.

Comment: There in no solution other than providing **correct** URL, if the URL you provided return 404 in canvas ensure you able to open it at all. Also ensure that your application namespace is `rummy_game` and you loading the correct application